# iOS Facebook Login linker error

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I have error messages below.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLQueryItem", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKApplicationDelegate.o)
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

What should I do?

Xcode 5.1.1
Target : iOS 7.0

Comment: Are you running with ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH enabled or disabled? Disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Add following `Framework` in your project settings.

```
Foundation.framework
CFNetwork.framework

FBSDKCoreKit.framework
FBSDKLoginKit.framework
FBSDKShareKit.framework
```

I hope it's help you.

Comment: The result is same. sorry. :-O

Comment: No, I don't. what pod file means?

Comment: you are added `FBSDKCoreKit.framework` in your project ?

Comment: Of course. Facebook dev tutorial says that. but I can't look for that error above. :-(

Comment: sorry ,i have no solution about this issue @DanielPark